# How is a variable with exponent called in the context of polynomials

Tags: notation, terminology, definition

A polynomial like
$$5 x^3 y^4 z + 4x z^4$$
is a sum of mononomials, $5 x^3 y^4 z$ and $4x z^4$ in this example. A monomial is made up of a coefficient, $5$ and $4$ in the example, and further it is made up of a list of ... how are the $x^3$, $y^4$, etc. called? Is there more compact name than talking about *variable with exponent*?

Comment: Simply *powers*.